# Printing the values on each level of a Binary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

The below code is for printing level-by-level in a binary tree:

```
//level order printing
public static void levelOrderPrint(Node root){
    Queue<Node> que = new LinkedList<Node>();
    Node mark = new Node(0);
    if(root != null){
        que.add(root);
        que.add(mark);
    }
    while(!que.isEmpty()){
        Node temp = que.poll();
        if(temp != mark)
        System.out.print(temp.key);
        if(temp == mark){
            if(que.peek() == mark || que.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }
            que.add(mark);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(temp.left != null){
            que.add(temp.left);
        }
        if(temp.right != null){
            que.add(temp.right);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there are any bugs or possible optimizations.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Review! To the best of your knowledge does this code works ? We won't review your code if you think there is bug in it, but if you think all your code works as expected we will happily review your code!

Answer (score 3):

This is good code.

### General

While it does what it says it will do, here is one beef I have with it, but it's a small one:

> ```
>     Node temp = que.poll();
>     if(temp != mark)
>     System.out.print(temp.key);
> ```

No braces, no indenting, code meaning is confused.....

That should be:

```
    Node temp = que.poll();
    if(temp != mark) {
        System.out.print(temp.key);
    }
```

There is a fair amount of debate about using '1-liner' `if` statements. The following are reasons why I despise them:

- the meaning of the code becomes white-space defined (like your indenting problem above). There are whole languages ( *cough* Pythong *cough* ) which are defined by whitespace. Java is defined by braces `{}`. Use them.
- If you use a version-control-system like CVS, SVN, Git, etc. then small changes to code blocks can become visually big in a change-log. Adding one line to the code means updating 3 lines.
- it can lead to bugs where people do not put braces in to lines where there should be two statements.
- etc.
- etc.

I don't like 1-liners Sam-I-Am

OK. But, as code goes, yours is good. How can it be better?

### Improvements

- You can make `mark` a private static final instance:

  ```
  private static final Node MARK = new Node(0);
  ```
- The following statement has redundancy:

  > ```
  >         if(que.peek() == mark || que.isEmpty()){
  >             return;
  >         }
  > ```

  it could be:

  ```
          if(que.isEmpty()){
              return;
          }
  ```

  It is not possible for the queue to have two consecutive marks, so the peek can never be a mark.
- Now, back to that indentation on the `println()` method call... here's your code:

  > ```
  >     if(temp != mark)
  >     System.out.print(temp.key);
  >     if(temp == mark){
  >         if(que.peek() == mark || que.isEmpty()){
  >             return;
  >         }
  >         que.add(mark);
  >         System.out.println();
  >     }
  > ```

  if you had correct braces, etc. you would see that you would be better off with an if/else condition, and that will save an `if` check:

  ```
      if(temp != mark) {
          System.out.print(temp.key);
      } else {
          if(que.peek() == mark || que.isEmpty()){
              return;
          }
          que.add(mark);
          System.out.println();
      }
  ```
- `System.out.println(...)` and all the `print*(...)` variants are slow (they are synchronized). Your code would be faster if you used a system like:

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  ....

      if (temp != mark) {
          sb.append(temp.key);
      } else {
          ....
          sb.append("\n");
      }

  ....
  System.out.print(sb);
  ```

### Conclusion

Otherwise, this is good code.